# Draw ListViewItem outsite the canvas of the listview template

Tags: wpf, listview, layout, canvas

I have a ListView that its ItemsPanelTemplate is a Canvas, and every item is a rectangle.
I'm trying to draw a Rectangle outside the Canvas in the position of (-50,-50) with no successive. can I do that somehow ?

[image]

The XAML:

```
<Grid >
    <ListView BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Rectangles}" Height="200" Width="200">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"  Value="{Binding Top, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfApplication2:RectangleModel}">
                <Rectangle Width="30" Height="30"  Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}" Canvas.Right="{Binding Right}" Fill="LightCoral"
                           ClipToBounds="False"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="LightBlue"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<RectangleModel> Rectangles { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Rectangles = new List<RectangleModel>();
        Rectangles.Add(new RectangleModel { Left = -50, Top = -50 });
        Rectangles.Add(new RectangleModel { Left = 0, Top = 0 });
        Rectangles.Add(new RectangleModel { Left = 50, Top = 50 });
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to `ClipToBounds="False"` in your ListViewItem style. Not sure it will work, just a suggestion

Comment: You can also try placing the ListView inside a Canvas, instead of placing it inside a Grid...

Comment: Thank you both, none of your advices worked for me.

Comment: I don't know that you will get this working correctly without drawing directly on the control exists where you are trying to draw. It sort of breaks the rules about what controls are responsible for painting. Personally I would either create a custom control for this behaviour or put down a canvas, then the listview and then paint directly on the Canvas when required.

Comment: Have you tried doing it through an animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong, but this seems to be rather simple problem (I may have completely assumed the wrong thing, but I'm not sure so I'm going with the assumption just in case).

You've defined your `ListView` to be 200 by 200 and your `Canvas` is taking all that space. Judging by your picture, I feel it is `Canvas` that you want to be of 200 by 200 not the `ListView`.

**Xaml:**

```
<Grid >
        <ListView BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Rectangles}">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"  Value="{Binding Top, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wpfApplication1:RectangleModel}">
                    <Rectangle Width="30" Height="10"  Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Top}" Fill="LightCoral"
                           ClipToBounds="False"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Background="LightBlue" ClipToBounds="False" Height="200" Width="200"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this style (I removed the scrollviewer from the default tamplate):

I agree with the comments saying a control that draws like this is doubtful.

```
<Window x:Class="CanvasListView.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:CanvasListView="clr-namespace:CanvasListView"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=CanvasListView:MainWindow,IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBorder" Color="#828790"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ListBorder}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListView BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Rectangles}" Height="200" Width="200">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"  Value="{Binding Top, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type CanvasListView:RectangleModel}">
                    <Rectangle Width="30" Height="30"   Fill="{Binding Color}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Background="LightBlue"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I added a color property in the viewmodel:

```
public string Color { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it via Popup, it looks well but I dont know whether it fits in your requirement or not

```
<Grid  Background="Transparent">
    <ListView BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Rectangles}" Height="200" Width="200">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"  Value="{Binding Top, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfApplication2:RectangleModel}">
                <Popup Width="30" Height="30"  Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}" Canvas.Right="{Binding Right}" 
                       IsOpen="True"
                       ClipToBounds="False">
                    <Rectangle Fill="LightCoral"/>
                </Popup>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="LightBlue"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

This gives same result as you want. But you need to work more on that like their relative positions and all.